# logic for default address for many addresses for user in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, collections

In my case, I made collection for user addresses and in address model, made a parameter as Boolean "isDefault" to make one address as a default one

address model

```
  class AddressModel {
  final String addressId,
      addressDetails,
      country,
      city,
      phoneNumber,
      phoneNumber2;
  bool isDefault;

  AddressModel(
      {required this.addressId,
      required this.addressDetails,
      required this.country,
      required this.city,
      required this.phoneNumber,
      required this.phoneNumber2,
      this.isDefault = false});

  factory AddressModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AddressModel(
      addressId: json["addressId"],
      addressDetails: json["addressDetails"],
      country: json["country"],
      city: json["city"],
      phoneNumber: json["phoneNumber"],
      phoneNumber2: json["phoneNumber2"],
      isDefault: json["isDefault"],
    );
  }
}
```

addressViewModel:

```
class AddressService extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<AddressModel> _addressesList = [];
  List<AddressModel> get addressesList => _addressesList;

  AddressModel? _addressModel;
  AddressModel? get defaultAddressModel => _addressModel;

  get isLoading => _isloading;
  bool _isloading = true;

  void setLoading(bool val) {
    _isloading = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  final CollectionReference _addressCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber ??
          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
      .collection("addresses");

  Future<void> getAddresses() async {
    setLoading(true);
    _addressesList = [];
    await _addressCollection.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        _addressesList
            .add(AddressModel.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
      }
    });
    setLoading(false);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> getDefaultAddress() async {
    await _addressCollection
        .where("isDefault", isEqualTo: true)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        _addressModel =
            AddressModel.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      }
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I can't think with a logic code to create to handle default address for user,
try to search with many solution to solve my problem, but I can't find any post explain anything like that,

I think using RadioTileList and that change the parameter of "isDefault" as true in one address and others as false, so I want anyone better than me to solve my problem, of suggest a new way to do that.

any ideas please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem and I want to share with you.

```
Future<void> changeDefaultAddress( AddressModel addressModel) async {

    await _addressCollection
        // .where("isDefault", isEqualTo: true)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        if (doc["isDefault"] == true)
          doc.reference.update({"isDefault": false});

        _addressCollection
            .doc(addressModel.addressId)
            .update({"isDefault": true});
      }
    }); 
  }
```